# Can a shebang refer to a remote program?

Tags: bash, shebang

Is it possible to add a shebang line to a file so that it refers to a program on a remote machine?

For example I don't have `wolframscript` installed on my local machine, but I do on a remote machine. So instead of

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript -cloud
2+2
```

can I run something like

```
#!username@192.168.0.1#22:/usr/bin/env wolframscript -cloud
2+2
```

or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a wrapper:

```
# The wrapper
$ cat wolfram-remote
#!/bin/bash
exec ssh username@192.168.0.1:/usr/bin/env -- wolframscript -cloud < "${1}"
# Make it executable
$ chmod +x wolfram-remote
```

Now you can use this wrapper in the shebang line:

```
#!./wolfram-remote
2+2
```

Comment: I run NixOS (which messes with shebang behavior), and so modified your answer to support NixOS. It's possible that the issue is not with your answer but the way that I translated it to NixOS.

Comment: Unf. I don't have NixOS for a test at hand. Can you show what you've changed?